# whats is wrong with this two operator calculator?

Tags: scheme, calculator, mit-scheme

I want to write a procedure named twoOperatorCalculator which will calculate left-associative infix addition and subtraction operations. Operations are given as a list and the output should be the result of these operations. Below is a sample output for this procedure:

```
1 ]=> (twoOperatorCalculator '(1 + 15 − 32/5 + −2))'<br/>
Value : 38/5<br/>
```

I tried so much but I could not find my fault. Error is like

```
1 ]=> (twooperatorcalculator '(1+2-3+2))'

;The object (1+2-3+2) is not applicable.
```

MY CODE

```
(define twooperatorcalculator 
  (lambda (exp) (
    (cond
      ((null? exp) 0)
      ((null? (cdr (cdr exp))) (car exp))
      ((eq? #\+ (cadr exp)) (+ (car (exp)) twooperatorcalculator (cdr (cdr exp))))
      ((eq? #\- (cadr exp)) (- (car (exp)) twooperatorcalculator (cdr (cdr exp))))))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(exp)
```

You are enclosing `exp` in parentheses, which means you are asking the interpreter to call the function currently bound to `exp`. But `exp` is a list, and cannot be called. You need to remove parentheses.

```
(... twooperatorcalculator ...)
```

Right after that, you have `twooperatorcalculator` that is *not* enclosed in parentheses, which means that you want to evaluate the symbol. Here it will be bound to a function object, which is not meaningful for a `+` operation. You need to enclose it in parentheses to call the function recursively.

Comment: In addition `+` in quoted datum is not a char but a symbol and `1+2-3+2` is probably considered one symbol when written without spaces. Also it looks like OP is matching `'`s